# AC_SUBST with dynamic variable name

Tags: autoconf, m4

I'm trying to create an m4 macro that basically calls AC_CHECK_SIZEOF(type) then uses AC_SUBST to define that variable for substitution. 
So given input of:

`AX_CHECK_SIZEOF_AND_SUBST(int, 4)`

I want all occurances of `@SIZEOF_INT@` to be replaced with 4

This is what I came up with so far, but obviously doesn't work:

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_CHECK_SIZEOF_AND_SUBST], [
    AC_CHECK_SIZEOF($1, $2)
    NAME=$(echo -n "SIZEOF_$1" | tr "a-z" "A-Z" | tr '*' 'P' | tr -c 'A-Z0-9' '_')
    echo "NAME=$NAME"
    AC_SUBST($NAME, $$NAME)
])
```

Comment: Please read the 3rd paragraph of http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Macro-Names.html.  Although I believe "AX_" does not conflict with any reserved namespace, it is advisable to avoid that name.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The AX_ prefix I got on the recommendation of ac-archive.sourceforge.net/doc/contribute.html (see last paragraph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with what you are trying to do is that `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` does not in fact define a variable named `SIZEOF_INT`.  In 2.68, the variable you want is named `ac_cv_sizeof_int`, but you should not use that as the name is subject to change in later versions.  The value is also written into confdefs.h, so another way to grab it is:

```
AC_PROG_AWK
AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([int])
SIZEOF_INT=$($AWK '/SIZEOF_INT/{print $3}' confdefs.h)
AC_SUBST([SIZEOF_INT])
```

(reading confdefs.h is also undocumented behavior and subject to change in future versions of autoconf, but is possibly more stable than looking at $ac_cv_sizeof_int.  Possibly, less stable, too. ;) YMMV)

To define your macro (please note my comment about the naming convention), you could do:

```
AC_DEFUN([wrp_CHECK_SIZEOF_AND_SUBST], [
    AC_REQUIRE([AC_PROG_AWK])
    AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([$1])
    m4_toupper(SIZEOF_$1)=$($AWK '
        /SIZEOF_[]m4_toupper($1)/{print $[]3}' confdefs.h)
    AC_SUBST(m4_toupper(SIZEOF_$1))
])
```

The version above does not handle `int *`, but for simplicity I will keep it there rather than replace it with the more general version:

```
AC_DEFUN([wrp_CHECK_SIZEOF_AND_SUBST], [
    AC_REQUIRE([AC_PROG_AWK])
    AC_CHECK_SIZEOF([$1])
    m4_pushdef([name],SIZEOF_[]m4_toupper(m4_translit($1,[ *],[_p])))
    name=$($AWK '/name/{print $[]3}' confdefs.h)
    AC_SUBST(name)
    m4_popdef([name])
])
```

Note:  I believe the `$()` notation should be avoided in portable configure scripts, and should be replaced with backticks.  However, I find backticks hideous.